# How to Run the time that the timezone is Denmark Copenhagen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, stopwatch

I found the code which is can run my stopwatch. but iwant to follow denmark country timezone to run my code. how to d

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
ElapsedTimeLogger = function(dateElementId, elapsedElementId, hiden, interval) {
    var container = $(elapsedElementId);
    var time = parseDate($(dateElementId).val());
    var interval = interval;
    var timer;

    function parseDate(dateString) {
        var date = new Date(dateString);
        return date.getTime();
    }

    function update() {
    var systemTime = new Date().getTime();
    elapsedTime = systemTime - time;
    container.html(prettyPrintTime(Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000)));
$(hiden).val(prettyPrintTime(Math.floor(elapsedTime / 1000)));
}

    function prettyPrintTime(numSeconds) {
        var hours = Math.floor(numSeconds / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((numSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = numSeconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
        var time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        return time;
    }

    this.start = function() {

        timer = setInterval(function() {update()}, interval * 1000);
    }

    this.stop = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    var timeLogger = new ElapsedTimeLogger("#date", "#elapsed","#stoppedid", 1);
    timeLogger.start();

   $("#confirm").click(function() { //Stop timer upon clicking the Confirm Button 
        timeLogger.stop();

    });

});

    </script>
```

Thank you in advance.
I cant post another question thats why i need to edit may other questions

Comment: you need to time in cookies or local storage then use that for your stopwatch

Comment: Can you give me some tips to do that? i dont have any idea how to start the cokies. all i know is start session

Comment: i have posted updated code as answer

Comment: not working sir :(

Answer (score 0):

remove `disabled` property of `input[name=stwa]` and add `readonly` property for there

Use `navigator.cookie` to save time on javascript

Comment: thank you for the reply. i already change the 'disabled' to 'readonly' but i dont know how to create 'navigator.cookie'. can you please show me a sample code? thank you

Comment: @JovelMarkDiaz , My English is no good but I hope this link can help you [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solutions

```js
  

  if(localStorage.getItem("sec"))
{
  var sec =  localStorage.getItem("sec");
  var min = localStorage.getItem("min");
  var hour = localStorage.getItem("hour");
  stopwatch("Start");
}else{
  var sec =  0;
  var min = 0;
  var hour = 0;
}
             
             
                
                function stopwatch(text) {
                
                   sec++;
                  if (sec == 60) {
                   sec = 0;
                   min = min + 1; }
                  else {
                   min = min; }
                  if (min == 60) {
                   min = 0; 
                   hour += 1; }

              localStorage.setItem("sec", sec);
                  localStorage.setItem("min", min);
                  localStorage.setItem("hour", hour);
                
                if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
                   document.clock.stwa.value = ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec;

                  if (text == "Start") { document.clock.theButton.value = "Start "; }
                  if (text == "Stop ") { document.clock.theButton.value = "Stop"; }

                  if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Start") {
                   window.clearTimeout(SD);
                   return true; }

                SD=window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);
                }

                function stop() {
                  x.stop();
                   document.getElementById('counter').value = formatTime(x.time());
                   clearInterval(clocktimer);
                   localStorage.clear();
                }
```

```html
<form name="clock" action="save_time_log.php" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control time_tracker" disabled name="stwa" placeholder="00:00:00">
                    </div>

                    <input type="button" name="theButton" onClick="stopwatch(this.value);" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-flat" value="Start" />
                    <input type="submit" name="stops" value="Stop" onClick="stop();" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-flat"/>

                </form>
```

Comment: thank you @CyberAbhay i will update you if it works. then i marked as solved :) i dont think so it is worked sir. but i want to run the time after the refresh the page.

Comment: i start the time -> http://prntscr.com/fbwxdb and then i refresh my page but the time is reset to 00:00:00 see the screenshot. thank you http://prntscr.com/fbwx79

Comment: i have little updated answer,this and previous one both working on my local(Chrome)

Comment: i thinks its working sir. but there is a problem. when i clicked stop the time wont reset to 0.  and i click start  the time is continue. how do i fix this? iwant to show the time is running in my txtfields

Comment: i see the error sir. the time is always on minutes.. when minutes upto 60. the hours is nothing change.